# Touchpad stopped working after suspend on a Toshiba L650

Tags: 10.10, mouse

I have a Toshiba L650, installed (dual boot) Ubuntu 10.10. Touchpad worked fine until I tried for the first time to suspend (I closed the screen on the keyboard).

The system never woke up again. Reset (battery disconnected and then reconnected), restart of the system, disk checks, and so on.

After that, everything works fine except the Touchpad, completely dead.
Rebooted again. The problem persists.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

A user in another forum suggested to

1. run `gconf-editor`
2. locate the key `/desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled`
3. and enable it.

I would be interested to know whether this worked!

Comment: I have a similar problem in 11.10. Touchpad stops working after suspend.

My laptop is a Clevo M55N.

I followed your instructions above, touchpad_enabled was ticked (and I guess, enabled) already. It did not work (for me).