# Touchpad stops working after suspend on a Clevo M55N

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, suspend

simple problem:

Touchpad stops working after suspend in Ubuntu 11.10. It is an annoying problem as I like to use my touchpad together with my mouse for convenience (unless I must use my touchpad because the mouse isn't available).

Can anyone help?

I also posted a comment under this unsolved question for a similar problem in 10.10: [Touchpad stopped working after suspend on a Toshiba L650](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22327/touchpad-stopped-working-after-suspend-never-woke-up-again)

Laptop make and model: CLEVO M55N.

xinput list in terminal gives:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius 2.4G Wireless Mouse and Keyboard   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Genius 2.4G Wireless Mouse and Keyboard   id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What's the make/model of your computer? Also, could you add to your question the output of running "xinput list" on a terminal? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my initial question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I also have this bug on 10.04 (at me same Elantech touchpad)!
I create script `/etc/pm/sleep.d/66my-sleep-resume` (66 - a start priority)

```
#!/bin/sh
case "${1}" in
        hibernate)
        # nothing   
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
        modprobe -r psmouse && modprobe psmouse
                ;;
esac
```

and now all works.

Comment: very good trick, do once and forget.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in terminal after resume:

```
synclient touchpadoff=0
```

If it works, you can write a script containing this command, and put the script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with an ASUS Q325UA laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are a lot of reasons why this could happen. A work-around that helped me in some cases is reloading the kernel module responsible for the mouse events:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

You should also check if using the Fn-Keys makes any difference.

Comment: I'll check this out and get back to you, as I see this only now (0:30 CET) and it is late here. I'm tired, good night and thanks.

Comment: I've checked this out. Using the commands given solves the problem temporarily, that is when I suspend again the problem resurfaces. Thanks for the suggestion, that solves the problem, although I'd rather go for a permanent solution rather than using those commands each and every time.

I don't understand what you mean as regards the function keys making any difference.

Thanks again.

Comment: this worked out fine for me. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

for me on xenial xubuntu xfce and Elantech touchpad this was not working:

modprobe **-rv** psmouse ;; modprobe **-v** psmouse **proto=imps** ;;

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/0000trackpad

#!/bin/sh
  case "$1" in
  suspend|hibernate)
     modprobe -rv psmouse ;;
  resume|thaw)
    modprobe -v psmouse proto=imps ;;
esac

dmesg | grep -i touch
[    1.876547] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[ 1077.028151] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6

grep -B 5 mouse /proc/bus/input/devices 
   I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
   N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
   P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
   S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
   U: Uniq=
   H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
<user>@<xenial>:~$ xinput
   ⎡ Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Video Bus                                  id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                               id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ WebCam SC-0311139N                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Problem described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1297144)

Only <kbd>Strg + Alt + F1</kbd> and back <kbd>Alt + F7</kbd> brings me the cursor back.

Answer (score 0):

The Power Manager (`dpkg -L pm-utils`) is invoked at the beginning and end of your Suspend/Resume. Read `man pm-powersave` and `man pm-suspend`. Also read `/usr/share/doc/pm-utils/README{,.debugging}`.

Some helpful Power Manager script is probably causing your touchpad problem. Either it's not saving/restoring the touchpad state or not reloading a needed module.

Look at `dmesg` after a reboot, and try to see how your touchpad is initialized. Compare the output of `lsmod` both post-boot-pre-suspend (when it works) and post-suspend (when it doesn't). If a module is missing from the latter, you're on your way to a solution.

Another debugging technique is to begin in the post-boot-pre-suspend state, and do:

1. `touch /tmp/before-time-date`
2. Close the Lid and Suspend.
3. Open the Lid and Resume.
4. Find system logs that have changed since step 1:
   `find /var/logs  -type f -anewer /tmp/before-time-date`
5. Look at the last several-to-many lines of each of these files. I use `less`, and have my favorite settings in an environment variable, `$LESS=-XMersj3`. so I can do:
   `sudo -v;find /var/logs -type f -anewer /tmp/before-date-time -print | xargs sudo less $LESS`
   then use less's `G` (uppercase ) command to get to the end of each file.

Comment: I'll try this when I find the time, I've got a very important exam in a week's time and I can't experiment much and/or use time for anything else but studying and unavoidable activities. I'll get back to you in a comment hereunder as soon as I try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with my wireless USB mouse/ keyboard (Logitech) on (L)ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Mouse cursor was stuck after pm-suspend. unplugging and re-plugging the USB fixed the issue.

Above workaround, creating a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, sorta worked. had to change the `psmouse` to hid_logitech.

With different hardware you will have to change the script accordingly, depending on what kernel modules you will need to reload.

**`/etc/pm/sleep.d/99_fixmouse`**

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  hibernate)
    #nothing
    ;;
  resume|thaw)
    modprobe -r hid_logitech
    modprobe  hid_logitech
    ;;
esac
```

don't forget to do a `chmod +x` on the above file.